# Ubuntu 18.04 stopped recognizing USB devices and SD card reader

Tags: drivers, usb, mount, sd-card

My sd card reader stopped working suddenly, so I tried an external sd card reader and turns out USB devices weren't recognized either.

Here's the full output for `lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at c2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at c2604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c2609000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at c2600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: c2500000-c25fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: c1000000-c1ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000c0ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c2400000-00000000c24fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at c2608000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at c2607000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 21
    Memory at c2605000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c2510000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-87-05-a0-dc-84-0c
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci

01:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at c2500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-88-05-a0-dc-84-0c

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at c1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at c2404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c2400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 0d-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Also, checking `dmesg` the message `mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card` appears everytime I insert an sd card. I don't really know where to check if there are messages for the usb devices when I connect them like the sd card. Any ideas? I don't think either the card reader or all the usb ports had died suddenly, I had to screw something up before but can't recall what.

Comment: Look in your BIOS for USB settings... enable/disable, or legacy vs other.

Comment: Messed around with the settings and didn't work. dmesg still shows the same message.

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer?

Comment: Yes. I just upgraded the kernel to see if it fixes it, so I'll reboot again now just in case.

Comment: Update: upgrading the kernel didn't fix it either.

Comment: I don't have any more ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Is there on the output, `rtsx_pci` driver. Search for the other answers related to RTS5229. Also `journalctl -xe -b 0 -p err` could tell you something.